# passing form data to mySQL through AJAX

Tags: php, forms, jquery

I am using JavaScript and AJAX to send form data to a php processing file to then populate an SQL database without refreshing the initial form page.

The php/SQL connection is working, but the form data is not being sent correctly.

There are two fields: a radio group called "choice", and a text field called "comments". When the DB is populated, the choice field is always "yes" (the first of the 3 radio buttons), and the comments field is always blank. I think the issue must be the way that the datastring is being constructed, but hours of tinkering have brought no success.

Here is the html form

```
<form id="paPoll">
  <label><input type="radio" name="RadioGroup1" value="yes" id="choice1">Yes</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="RadioGroup1" value="no" id="choice2">No</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="RadioGroup1" value="dont_know" id="choice3">I Don't Know</label>
  <label for="comments">Comments?</label><input name="comments" type="text" id="comments" size="25" maxlength="60">   
  <input type="button" name="form_process" id="form_process" value="submit" onClick="$.fn.removeMbMenu($.mbMenu.options.actualOpenedMenu,true);" />
</form>
```

here is the Javascript/AJAX function

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
      $("#form_process").click(function() {
        var choice = $("#choice").val();
        var comments = $("#comments").val();
        var dataString = 'choice='+ choice + '&comments=' + comments;

        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "**ABSOLUTE URL TO PROCESSOR**",
          data: dataString
        });
      });
    });
</script>
```

here is the php processor

```
<?php
$choice = $_POST ['choice'];
$comments = $_POST ['comments'];
//perform insert
    $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO paPoll 
    (choice, comments)      
    VALUES  
    ('$choice', '$comments')");         
        if (!query) {
           die("Database query failed: " . mysql_error());
        }
?>
```

Thoughts or suggestions?

I found a very similar question here, but the thread is 3 years old. A user suggested this

```
//Instead of using
data: dataString
//use
data : {param: value, param2: value2}
```

but I'm not sure how, or in what format he means to get the param values.

Thank you
-syllable

Comment: Can you add the relevant part of the HTML form, too? I think radio buttons mustn't have ID's, but `name`'s instead, and you have to figure out which one is checked (all the buttons share one `name`).

Comment: the radio can't within the same id. make this choice0,choice1,choice2

Comment: Thanks guys, I changed the id's to choice0,1 etc. That's one I fixed a while ago and must have undone with an angry ctrl-z tantrum.

Comment: @sylable: the param values when yousing a hash for the data are strings (or things that can be accurately cast as strings like numbers). jquery basically takes this hash and runs `$.serialize` on it transforming it into the string you are trying to manually encode. Speaking of which if youre going to do it manually i believe you need to `encodeURIComponent()` each value.

Answer (score 1):

Were it me i would just make this easier on myself by using the [Form plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/). Its already got an `ajaxSubmit` set of functions to make ajaxify your form with little effort. IT also has the handy `formSerialize` function which will serialize a form for ajax submission or to append to a query string for a link. :-)

That said an easier way without the plugin and utilizing your existing code:

```
$("#form_process").click(function() {

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "**ABSOLUTE URL TO PROCESSOR**",
    data: {
      'choice': $("input[@name=RadioGroup1]:checked").val(), 
      'comments':  $("#comments").val()
    }
  });

});
```

Either way though, you also need to change all your radio inputs to have unique ID's (or no ID at all)... you cant use the same one as its required that all id attributes have unique values within the document.

Comment: Thank you very much prodigitalson. This worked to populate the correct radio selection, but the comments field is still blank each time. Also, thanks for the Form plugin; however, I tried implementing it with no success. That's why I switched back to the more basic AJAX function.

Comment: try changing the th comments input so that the `name` and `id` attributes are different from one another. for example `<input name="comments" id="field_comments"  type="text" size="25" maxlength="60" />` and then use `$('#field_comments').val()` to get the value or `$('input[@name=comments]').val()` Also if youd like to post separate question regarding your issues with the form plugin id be happy to take a look :-)

Comment: Thank you for your continued help. Again no go. I am really puzzled and frustrated by this. I changed the id to a different value and tried $('#get_comments').val() but the comments field still did not populate. The $('input[@name=comments]').val(), threw an unrecognized expression error, even though that's what I'm using for the radio group. I appreciate your help offer with the Form plugin, but I can't tell you what issue I was having since the result was the same; no comment field population. -syllables

Answer (score 0):

several week ago i have the same problem, and i just try using the old way like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
      $("#form_process").click(function() {
        //$("#choice").val(); //you cannot use the same id for more than 1 tag
        var choice = 0; 
             if(document.getElementById("choice1").checked) choice='Yes';
        else if(document.getElementById("choice2").checked) choice='No';
        else if(document.getElementById("choice3").checked) choice='Dont Know';

        var comments = document.getElementById('comments').value; //$("#comments").val();
        var dataString = 'choice='+ choice + '&comments=' + comments;

        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "**ABSOLUTE URL TO PROCESSOR**",
          data: dataString
        });
     });
   });
</script>
```

really i don't know, i think this is not the best way but this work for me :)

Comment: Thank you for the answer bungdito, good thinking with the radio group if statement. This didn't work for me however.