# External PHP data not passing through AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm working on creating a simple online booking system using PHP and AJAX.

The current layout is:
Each booking grabs a preset list of items then users can add additional items that they need.
To do this I have set up an AJAX button that calls a new drop down list each time its clicked. (This means a page could have 1 additional item or even 20, depending on how many they need.)

Once the additional items have been selected, they can then submit the form and will be guided to a confirmation page that is meant to list what they have chosen.

The issue:
None of the data is being carried through from any of the drop down lists that get added.

My AJAX script and php code on page 1 is:

```
<script>
function changeIt()
{
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "details.php"
}).done(function( result ) {
$("#msg1").append( "" +result);
});
}   
</script>

<form name ="addequip" id="addequip" action="confirmbooking.php" method="post">
<input type='button' value="Add Item" onClick="changeIt()"/>
<div id="msg1"></div>
<input type='submit' value='submit'/>
```

details.php:

```
<?php
require_once("dbconn.php");
$sql = "SELECT REFERENCE, DESCRIPTION FROM descEquip";
$result = mysql_query($sql,$conn);
?>

<select name="equip">
<?php while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { ?>
<option value="<?php echo $row["REFERENCE"];?>"><?php echo $row["DESCRIPTION"];?></option><?php } ?>
</select>
```

And lastly my confirmation page is:

```
<?php $item = $_POST['equip']; ?>
<?php echo $item ?>
```

I'm not too sure if i need to add something to the AJAX script in order for this to work as intended or if something needs to be changed in the details.php? (I'm very new to AJAX)

I have viewed a previous question '[passing form data to mySQL through AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6784599/passing-form-data-to-mysql-through-ajax)' and I couldn't make it work for me.

Lastly, for additional lists (when more than 1 item is required) do I need to have a feature that states each equip list have a different name? like`name="equip<?php echo $i ?> where $i = 1++;`

Any tips or examples would be appreciated,
thanks.

Comment: your `$.ajax()` has no `data:` parameter, so you're simply firing off an http request with NO form data included.

Comment: have you confirmed that your php is outputting a db result? also if you want to pull data down from your php script you'll want to GET and not post.  additionally, your dataType should be set to HTML

Comment: I have confirmed that my php is outputting a db result. And when it comes to AJAX, I'm in in the dark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never assume all will work as you want it - check if sth goes wrong in your code:

```
var jqxhr = $.ajax(
    {
        type: 'GET',
        async: false,
        url: 'details.php',
        success: function(data, textStatus /* always 'success'  */, jqXHR)
                 {
                    // ok if we are here it means that communication between browser and apache was successful

                    alert( 'on_ajax_success data=[' + data + ']  status=[' + textStatus + ']' );
                    $("#msg1").innerHTML( result );
                 }
        ,
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
                {
                    alert( 'ERROR: [operation failed]' );
                }
    });
```

Moreover - use Firefox with Firebug installed so that you can see your ajax queries/responces.

Comment: I think I've confused myself. So Im getting a success message with each time I press my 'add item' button but still nothing is coming through when I press submit? Your code is to be added inside my already existing function?

Comment: Ok Now I'm understanding it a lot better after reading/ viewing some more tutorials but I'm still confused on how to get the information to go to the next page when I hit the submit button